react native ios runtime error: dyld__abort_with_payload Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
Have runtime error on app start on some ios devices, and i dont know what device specifications need to reproduce this error
first screenshot
second
runtime throws this error
dyld[2658]: Symbol not found: (_$s7Network11IPv4AddressVMn)
Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FCF16909-7598-4C5F-9B73- 
C3D36879FEED/HappCore.app/HappCore.debug.dylib'
Expected in: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Network.framework/Network'

screenshot
i found similar issues, but they dont have solutions for me

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I found the cause of this problem, it was just My Tracker SDK, i removed library and my project start working

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
